# Songs play simultaneously in Media player. Android studio

Tags: android, media-player

I created a music application in android studio. The problem i get is that when I want to play a second song in the middle of the first song, it plays on top of the first song. The first song does not stop playing. It continues to play with the second selected song.

In the app, I have two activites for MainActivity.java has the list of songs and NowPlaying.java plays the song.

The codes of the two java class are given below:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] songList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    populateList();
}


private void populateList() {
    songList = new String[]{"Jalma", "Demons", "Parelima", "Mero Balyakal Ko Sathi", "Audai Jadai",
            "Case 420", "Euta Sathi", "Cheerleader"};

    ListAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            songList);

    ListView theList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theList);
    theList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    theList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ListView theList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theList);

            String selectedSong = (String) (theList.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Intent toSecondActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NowPlaying.class);
            toSecondActivity.putExtra("playSong", selectedSong);
            startActivity(toSecondActivity);
        }
    });


}
```

}

NowPlaying.java

```
public class NowPlaying extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer song;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_now_playing2);

    song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.demons);
    song.start();
    song.pause();

    selectSong();
    pauseButton();
    getSongList();
    getNextButton();
    getPreviousButton();

}

/**
 * Method for selecting the song
 * Moves to startSong method
 */
public void selectSong(){

    checkIfSongIsPlaying();
        String nextPlay = getIntent().getStringExtra("playSong");
    TextView lyricsBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lyricsBox);
    lyricsBox.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        if (nextPlay.equals("Demons")) {
            song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.demons);
            lyricsBox.setText(R.string.demonsLyrics);
        }
        else if(nextPlay.equals("Jalma")){
            song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jalma);
            lyricsBox.setText(R.string.jalmaLyrics);
        }
        else if(nextPlay.equals("Parelima")){
            song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.parelima);
            lyricsBox.setText(R.string.parelimaLyrics);
        }

        else if (nextPlay.equals("Case 420")) {
            song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.case420);
            lyricsBox.setText(R.string.case420Lyrics);
        } else if (nextPlay.equals("Mero Balyakal Ko Sathi")) {
            song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.balyakalsathi);
            lyricsBox.setText(R.string.balyakalSathi);
        } else if (nextPlay.equals("Euta Sathi")) {
            song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.eutasathi);
            lyricsBox.setText(R.string.eutaSathi);

        } else if (nextPlay.equals("Audai Jadai")) {
            song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audaijadai);
            lyricsBox.setText(R.string.audaijadaiLyrics);

        } else if (nextPlay.equals("Cheerleader")) {
            song = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cheerleader);
            lyricsBox.setText(R.string.cheerleaderLyrics);
        }
        playSong();

}

public void checkIfSongIsPlaying(){

    if(song !=null){
        song.pause();

    }
}

/**
 * Method to start song (play the song)
 *
 */
public void playSong(){
    song.start();
    getSongtitle();
    getSeekbar();
    onSongCompletion();

}

/**
 * Method for pause Button
 * to pause song once clicked and change button background to play image
 * Again play the song if the button is pressed again. and change background back to pause image
 */

public void pauseButton(){
    final Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (song.isPlaying()) {
                playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.playbutton);
                song.pause();
            } else {
                playButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausebutton);
                song.start();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Method to get the song title from first java file and display in the title
 */
public void getSongtitle(){

    String nextPlay = getIntent().getStringExtra("playSong");
    TextView songTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
    songTitle.setText(nextPlay);


}//end of getSongtitle method


/**
 * Method for song list button
 * Goes back to the first java file once the button is cliked,
 * displays the song list
 */
public void getSongList(){
    Button lyricsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lyricsButton);
    lyricsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(NowPlaying.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}



Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getSeekbar();
    }
};


/**
 * Method to update the seekbar.
 * implement touch in seekbar to change song position
 */
        public void getSeekbar(){
            SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
           seekBar.setMax(song.getDuration());
            seekBar.setProgress(song.getCurrentPosition());
            seekBar.postDelayed(run, 1000);
            TextView endTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endTimer);
            TextView startTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startTimer);

            double  finalTime = song.getDuration();
            double startTime = song.getCurrentPosition();
            double timeRemaining = finalTime - song.getCurrentPosition();
            startTimer.setText(String.format("%d:%d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long)startTime ), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) startTime) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) startTime))));
            endTimer.setText(String.format("%d:%d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) timeRemaining) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining))));

            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                int seek_to;

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    seek_to = progress;
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    song.seekTo(seek_to);
                }
            });
        }


/**
 * Lists the song list after song is completeted
 */
public void onSongCompletion(){

    song.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer song) {
            song.reset();
            startActivity(new Intent(NowPlaying.this, MainActivity.class));

        }
    });
}



/**
 * Method for next button
 * the song skips every 10 seconds once clicked
 */

public void getNextButton(){

    Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int startTime = song.getCurrentPosition();
            int forwardTime = 10000;
            startTime += forwardTime;
            if (startTime <= song.getDuration()) {
                song.seekTo(startTime);
            } else {
                song.stop();

            }
        }
    });

} // end of getNextButton


/**
 * Method for previous button
 * the song skips back 10 seconds once clicked
 */
public void getPreviousButton(){
    Button previousButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previousButton);
    previousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int startTime = song.getCurrentPosition();
            int previousTime = 10000;
            startTime -= previousTime;

            if (startTime >= 0) {
                song.seekTo(startTime);
            } else {
                song.seekTo(0);
                song.start();

            }
        }
    });
} //end of getPreviousButton method
```

}

What I want is that if the user wants to play a second song, while the first song is being played. The first song to be stopped and the second song to be played. In the app, however, the lyrics, seekbar, time gets updated but the song gets played simultaneously(on top of each other).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write song.stop(); instead of song.pause(); on checkIfSongIsPlaying. You can also write song.reset(); to make sure before you change the song.

Let me know if that works out

Comment: I used this code 
if (song != null){
            try {
               song.stop();
                song.reset();

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            selectSong();
        }
        else{
          selectSong();
        }
    }

and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

- This is happening because a new object of `NowPlaying` is created on each time you click am item in `listview` (This creates new `MediaPlayer` objects). To overcome this, you may make `NowPlaying` as a singleton class.
- Also, have a look at the methods you have called in `onCreate` method. Calling the `pause` method immediately after `start` makes no sense.

### Example:

MainActivity.java

```
....
....
 String selectedSong = (String) (theList.getItemAtPosition(position));
 // instead of intents use the advantage of singleton class.
 NowPlaying.getInstance(selectedSong);
....
....
```

NowPlaying.java

Better create a new java file for this, u can set the values of activity using this with get and set methods.

```
public class public class NowPlaying extends AppCompatActivity {
    NowPlaying nowplaying; 
    String selectedSong;
    MediaPlayer song;
    public static NowPlaying getInstance(String selectedSong){
        if(nowplaying == null){
             nowplaying = new NowPlaying();
        }
        this.selectedSong = selectedSong;
        return nowplaying;
    }
```

place these functions apart.

```
        // these two methods are calling one after the other which won't allow the song to play completely.
        song.start();
        song.pause(); // keep this method in different method such as pause btn click listener.
        .....
        ... rest of code ...
        .....

   }
```

Hope, this helps..!